# How do I create a legend for both color and shape in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot where I am graphing statistics for two sets. The shape of the points indicate which X-axis population that data point is for and the color of the point indicates what Y-axis population that is for

My table looks as such

```
comp    source2 y   SEy source1 x   SEx color   shape
PopA    PopAlpha    0.3 0.002   PopOne  0.1 0.2 green   1
PopB    PopAlpha    0.5 0.1 PopOne  0.3 0.8 green   1
PopC    PopAlpha    0.4 0.1 PopOne  0.2 0.4 green   1
PopA    PopBeta 0.3 0.1 PopOne  0.1 0.1 blue    1
PopB    PopBeta 0.2 0.01    PopOne  0.1 0.1 blue    1
PopC    PopBeta 0.1 0.1 PopOne  0.213501    0.00204 blue    1
PopA    PopAlpha    0.3 0.2 PopTwo  0.2 0.2 green   8
PopB    PopAlpha    0.1 0.2 PopTwo  0.2 0.01    green   8
PopC    PopAlpha    0.3 0.1 PopTwo  0.2 0.9 green   8
PopA    PopBeta 0.2 0.4 PopTwo  0.3 0.1 blue    8
PopB    PopBeta 0.3 0.1 PopTwo  0.3 0.1 blue    8
PopC    PopBeta 0.1 0.1 PopTwo  0.2 0.1 blue    8
```

and my code is such

```
read.table("example.txt", header = TRUE) -> tbl
require(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(data = tbl,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
  geom_point(colour=tbl$color, mapping=aes(shape=tbl$shape)) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y-SEy,ymax = y+SEy,width=0),colour=tbl$color) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x-SEx,xmax = x+SEx,height=0),colour=tbl$color) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) + scale_shape_identity()
  #+ scale_colour_manual(name = "Y population",labels = c("PopAlpha", "PopBeta"),values = c("green", "blue"))
  #+ scale_shape_manual(name = "X population",labels = c("PopOne","PopTwo"),values = c(1,8))  
ggsave(plot=plot,height=6,width=7, filename="example2.pdf", useDingbats=FALSE)
plot(plot)
dev.off()
```

When I try to uncomment out the legend lines, I get "Error in +scale_shape_manual(name = "X population", labels = c("PopOne",  :
invalid argument to unary operator"

Can someone help me figure what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

I need the legend to have one portion indicating color and one indicating shape. My actual dataset has four colors and seven shapes, so I can't have a legend that explains all combinations.

```
structure(list(comp = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("PopA", "PopB", "PopC"), class = "factor"), source2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("PopAlpha", "PopBeta"), class = "factor"), y = c(numbers), SEy = c(numbers), source1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("PopOne", "PopTwo"), class = "factor"), x = c(numbers), SEx = c(numbers), color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("blue", "green"), class = "factor"), shape = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L)), .Names = c("comp", "source2", "y", "SEy", "source1", "x", "SEx", "color", "shape"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Please output your data with `dput`

Comment: Write dput(tbl) and post the output

Comment: there are probably some typos in your code. for one thing (ggplot(data = tbl,aes(x = x,y = y))) I don't see x and y in your dataset...and your color (colour=tbl$color) needs to be set inside the aes() expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the + at the end of the line rather than the start of the next.

```
ggplot(data = tbl,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
  geom_point(colour=tbl$color, mapping=aes(shape=tbl$shape)) +  
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) + scale_shape_identity()
```

Code this far is syntactically complete. So the next lines are taken as being added together rather than being added to the previous.

```
 + scale_colour_manual(name = "Y population",labels = c("PopAlpha", "PopBeta"),values = c("green", "blue"))
 + scale_shape_manual(name = "X population",labels = c("PopOne","PopTwo"),values = c(1,8))
```

Simply move the +s to the ends of the previous lines so the lines are not complete.

I make this mistake every time I get ggplot2 out.

Comment: Rather than making columns for colour and shape in the table, you could use set colour = source2 and shape = source1 in the mapping. This makes the code simpler
plot <- ggplot(data = tbl,aes(x = x, y = y, shape = source1, colour = source2)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y-SEy,ymax = y+SEy,width=0)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x-SEx,xmax = x+SEx,height=0)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) + #scale_shape_identity() + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Y population") + 
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "X population")  
plot(plot)

Comment: you can still set them iwith   scale_colour_manual(name = "Y population", values = c("blue", "green"))

Comment: You can add a breaks argument with the levels in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain a variable in the legend, you just need to map it including that variable in aes.

Moreover as `shape` is a numeric variable, it needs to be converted to factor

```
ggplot(data = tbl,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
geom_point(mapping=aes(shape=factor(shape),color=color)) +  
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Y population",labels = c("PopBeta", "PopAlpha"),values = c("blue", "green"))+
scale_shape_manual(name = "X population",labels = c("PopOne","PopTwo"),values = c(1,8))
```

Comment: Try writing c("blue","green") instead

Comment: this labels = c("PopBeta", "PopAlpha"),values = c("blue", "green"))  will give you what you want

Comment: Exactly as it is in the post